# Evaluate using combinatorial argument or otherwise :$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\left(j\binom{n}{i}+i\binom{n}{j}\right)$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Evaluate using combinatorial argument or otherwise $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\left(j\binom{n}{i}+i\binom{n}{j}\right)$$
**My Attempt**

By plugging in values of $i=0,1,2,3$ I could observe that this double summation is nothing but $$\left(1+2+3+...+n\right)\left(\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+...+\binom{n}{n}\right)-\left(1\binom{n}{1}+2\binom{n}{2}+...+n\binom{n}{n}\right)$$which simplifies to $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.2^n-n.2^{n-1}=n^22^{n-1}$$ which is indeed the answer.

But I am having problem to do this summation by combinatorial argument.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\left(j\binom{n}{i}+i\binom{n}{j}\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{i}\binom{j}{1}+\binom{n}{j}\binom{i}{1}\right)$$

That is as far as I could go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, note that
$$\sum_{i,j: i<j} (a_{ij} + a_{ji}) = \sum_{i,j: i < j} a_{ij} + \sum_{i,j: i > j} a_{ij} = \sum_{i,j: i\not= j} a_{ij} =  \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} - \sum_i a_{ii}.$$
Taking $a_{ij}=j\binom{n}{i}$ yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j: i<j} \left(j\binom{n}{i} + i\binom{n}{j}\right) 
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n j\binom{n}{i} - \sum_{i=0}^n i\binom{n}{i} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n j \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} - \sum_{i=1}^n i\binom{n}{i} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n j 2^n - n\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n-1}{i-1} \\
&= \frac{n(n+1)}{2} 2^n - n2^{n-1} \\
&= n^2 2^{n-1}.
\end{align}

---

For a combinatorial interpretation of
$$\sum_{i,j: i\not= j} j\binom{n}{i} = n^2 2^{n-1},$$ maybe consider committees with a chair and vice chair (different from the chair) chosen from people $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$, subject to the restriction that $0$ cannot be the chair.  The RHS is clear.  For the LHS, $j$ could represent the larger of the chair and vice chair, leaving $j$ choices $\{0,1\dots,j-1\}$ for the smaller of the two, and $i$ could represent the number of members chosen from among $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an analytical way.
There are probably simpler ones.

$\begin{array}\\
a(n)
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\left(j\binom{n}{i}+i\binom{n}{j}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}j\binom{n}{i}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}i\binom{n}{j}\\
&=b(n)+c(n)\\
b(n)
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}j\binom{n}{i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}j\\
c(n)
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}i\binom{n}{j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}i\binom{n}{j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}j
\qquad \text{(swap } i \text{ and } j)\\
b(n)+c(n)
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}j+\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}j\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}j+\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}j\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}(\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}j+\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}j)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}(\sum_{j=0}^{n}j-i)\\
&=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}-\sum_{i=0}^{n}i\binom{n}{i})\\
&=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}2^n-n2^{n-1}\\
&=n2^{n-1}(n+1-1)\\
&=n^22^{n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

Reindex the double sum as a product of two single sums minus diagonal terms:
$$\sum_{0\le i,j\le n,i\ne j}i\binom nj=\sum_{0\le i,j\le n}i\binom nj-\sum_{i=0}^ni\binom ni$$
$$=\left(\sum_{i=0}^ni\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj\right)-\sum_{i=0}^ni\binom ni$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)}2\cdot2^n-\sum_{i=0}^ni\binom ni$$
This last sum is well-known to be $n2^{n-1}$ (and can be proved combinatorially), so the answer is
$$n(n+1)2^{n-1}-n2^{n-1}=n^22^{n-1}$$